# My simple C program won't execute this for loop (CS50 cash)

Tags: c, cs50

I want the program to give the user the least amount of coins needed for their change (CS50) but it won't execute the second for loop :/ Anyone have any suggestions?
It executes the first for loop fine but won't give the correct answer if I input .60 (should output 3, but just gives 2).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    //correct input loop
    float n;
    do
    {
        n = get_float("Change owed: ");
    }
    while (n<0);

    //to convert from float to int 
    int cents = round(n*100);

    printf("You are owed %i cents\n" ,cents);

    //for reference
    int coins = 0;
    int j;

    //quarters
    for (j= cents; j > 0; j = j - 25)
    {
        if (j>=25)
        {
        coins = coins + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ;
        }
    }
    printf("quarters: %i\n", coins);

    //dimes
    int k;

    for(k = j; k > 0; k = k - 10)
    {
        if(k>=10)
        {
            coins = coins + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ;
        }
    }
    printf("quarters and dimes: %i\n" ,coins);

    printf("total: %i\n" , coins);
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to figure out what is going on.  The contents of cs50.h would need to be added.

Comment: You're subtracting from the number of cents remaining even in cases where the coin value is too large so when you move to the next loop, the number of cents remaining is negative.

Comment: You have not reduced the `cents` remaining as you make change.

Comment: Is SO cool with folks posting homework?

Comment: @wcochran it's fine if they have made an effort and gone wrong (and not expecting a pat answer). But we do like them to [read the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @WeatherVane They are using `j` for the quarters to represent the cents, and then using that to set the value of `k` to be the cents for dimes.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons yeah but as you mentioned earlier, `j` can go negative.

Comment: The first loop only finishes when the statement `j > 0` is false. So after the first loop, `j` is either zero, or negative.

Comment: Some `while` loops might work better. `while(cents >= coinvalue)` or even think about using the `/` division and `%` modulus operators.

Comment: @WeatherVane Or, in the vein of `/` and `%`, there's the standard `div` functions that perform both operations in a likely more optimized fashion.

Comment: @wcochran See here for an unofficial compromise regarding homework: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in how you are performing your loops

```
for (j= cents; j > 0; j = j - 25) // you are subtracting 25 until j goes negative rather than when there's enough change left to form a quarter
{
    if (j>=25)
    {
    coins = coins + 1;
    }
    else // also this does nothing
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

Instead, you can modify the condition of your for-loop so it stops when `j` is less than 25:

```
for (j = cents; j >= 25; j-=25)
{
    if (j>=25)
    {
        ++coins;
    }
}
```

But now we can see the condition for the loop is the same as the condition on the if statement, so we can get rid of that:

```
for (j = cents; j >= 25; j-=25)
{
    ++coins;
}
```

Or we can even put it up there in the after-expression of the loop with the j-=25:

```
for (j = cents; j >= 25; j-=25, ++coins);
```

Similarly for the dimes loop:

```
for(k = j; k >= 10; k-=10, ++coins);
```

There are even better ways to achieve the same end results, but this answer is intended to help with the algorithm you were attempting to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze your first loop, assuming `cents` is `60`:

```
for (j= cents; j > 0; j = j - 25)
{
    if (j>=25)
    {
    coins = coins + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

1. `j` is set to 60
2. `60` is greater than `0`, so we enter the body of the loop
3. `60` is greater than or equal to `25`, add `1` to `coins`, `coins == 1`
4. Subtract `25` from `j`, `j` is now `35`
5. `35` is greater than `0`, so we enter the body of the loop
6. `35` is greater than `25`, add `1` to `coins`, `coins == 2`
7. Subtract `25` from `j`, `j` is now `10`
8. `10` is greater than `0`, so we enter the body of the loop
9. `10` is *not* greater than or equal to `25`, so we don't do anything with `coins`
10. **SUBTRACT `25` FROM `j`, `j` IS NOW `-15`**
11. `-15` is not greater than `0`, so we exit the loop.

And here's our problem - when you enter the second loop, **`j` is less than `0`**, so the second loop doesn't execute at all.

You don't want to do another subtraction if `j` is less than `25`; you want to exit the loop immediately at that point.  You should change the condition of the first loop to

```
for ( j = cents; j >= 25; j -= 25 ) // shorthand for j = j - 25
{
  coins++;                          // shorthand for coins = coins + 1;
}
```

Not only is the body of the loop now *much* simpler, you exit *before* `j` goes negative.  You should do the same thing for the second loop - that is, check that
`j >= 10` as the condition.